# What is the difference between firmware update and apt-get update?

Tags: firmware, update

What is the difference between rpi-update (firmware) and apt-get update and apt-get upgrade?

/Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rpi-update` updates the firmware for the Raspberry Pi. It does not change any packages.

`apt-get update` updates the package listings for the Debian operating system, but does not upgrade the packages themselves.

`apt-get upgrade` upgrades any packages that have new versions. You usually run this after you run `apt-get update`.

Note: for these commands to do anything, you have to prefix them with `sudo` to get administrative privileges, else they won't work.

Comment: @Christain If you're confused by the expression `firmware`, it refers to the files and drivers that interact with the Raspberry Pi hardware, such as the Broadcom chip. These are not kept in the normal `apt` repositories, and so have to be upgraded separately.

Comment: And by that, firmware files are situated on the SD card and does not alter any code within the SOC's?

Comment: @Christian correct. they help the software interface with the Pi. they don't change any code inside the SOCs.